# Rails: reference image in engine path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

Given a Rails engine contains a Sass stylesheet which defines a mixin or placeholder selector which in return references an image:

```
%foo
  background-image: image-url(…PATH…)
```

And I would like to use this placeholder selector **in the main application**, how does the `PATH` have to look like so that the image can actually be found? Or is there any additional configuration necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is very simple, using `asset-url` instead of `image-url` will do the trick:

```
ENGINE:
  app/
    assets/
      images/
        foo.png

%foo
  background-image: asset-url('foo.png')
```